# PHP5-FPM w/Apache2 FastCGI Error -1 Copy file failed

Tags: apache2, php, error-handling

I'm using php5-fpm with apache2 and I'm receiving the below error message.

```
FastCGI: comm with server "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/php5.fcgi" aborted: error parsing headers: invalid Status '-1 Copy file failed', referer: https://www.website.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer
```

Comment: post index.php  please

Comment: The index is default for Joomla 3.3.3. The index isn't an issue sense it worked a week ago and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: hard for me to help with what little information you posted. Simply stating is it broken or that it worked a week ago does not help. What did you change? Copy failed suggests a permissions problem somewhere.

Comment: Here is the code [link](http://pastie.org/9546516)

Comment: Nothing obvious there and it becomes tedious to go through all the php. Check the ownership and permissions of /var/www/html (or /var/www depending on your version of Apache and Ubuntu). Or wherever index.php is located.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I just did a chown -R www-data:www-data * current /var/www PWD and works now. Thanks Bodzi

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, this was a permissions problem.

> Thanks I just did a chown -R www-data:www-data * current /var/www PWD and works now.